# resizing for svg.rect element using jquery-ui resizable() interaction does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, svg

I tried to make svg.rect element draggable and resizable. While draggable works , resizable does not. I dont even see the resize cursor on the UI element.

```
<div id="wfPage" >
    <svg width="99%" height="2000">
        <rect class="svgRects"  x="100" y="20" width="140" height="70" /> 
    </svg>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.svgRects')
        .draggable() // WORKS
            .on('drag', function(event, ui){
                event.target.setAttribute('x', ui.position.left);
                event.target.setAttribute('y', ui.position.top);
            });

    $('.svgRects')
        .resizable()  // DOES NOT WORK
            .on( 'resize', function( event, ui ) {
            event.target.setAttribute('width', ui.size.width);
            event.target.setAttribute('height', ui.size.height);
            });
});
```

Comment: I don't know much about Javascript but it triggered me that you wrote `'drag'` in the working part but `"resize"` in the not working part. Could that  (the use of different quotation marks) be the problem?

Comment: single or double quotes do not matter. Though for consistency I put single quotes now. Behavior is still same.